# How to use getCollection() in this case

Tags: php, magento, collections, module, resources

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

i created one module everything is working fine,But i'm having the problem with getCollection().

```
$attrid = 64;
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/xyz')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('c_id',$attrid);
```

it is working if i have only one record in table for this condition `where c_id = $attrid`

but actually `where c_id = $attrid` i'm going to have multiple records at that time its giving the following error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:74:"Item (Namespace_Module_Model_Xyz) with the same id "64" already exist";i:1;s:6099:"#0 /var/www/com2/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(576): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Namespace_Module_Model_Xyz))
```

Also i tried like this

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    ->addFieldToFilter('c_id', array('eq'=>$attrid)
));
```

**Table1** (c_id is Primary Key)

```
c_id    title    value
-----   -----    -----
 64      my       1
```

**Table2** (autoc_id is Primary Key)

```
autoc_id     c1      c2     c3      c4      c-id
--------    ----    ----   ----    ----     ----
1           a1       b1     c1      d1      64
2           a2       b2     c2      d2      64
3           a3       b3     c3      d3      64
4           a4       b4     c4      d4      64
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <module>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Module</module>
                    <frontName>module</frontName>
                </args>
            </module>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <module>
                    <file>module.xml</file>
                </module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <module>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Module</module>
                    <frontName>module</frontName>
                </args>
            </module>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <module module="module">
                <title>Title</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="module">
                        <title>title2</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>module/adminhtml_module</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </module>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Namespace_Module>
                            <title>Title Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Namespace_Module>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <module>
                    <file>module.xml</file>
                </module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
<global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </module>
            <module_mysql4>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <module>
                        <table>table1</table>
                    </module>
                </entities>
                <entities>
                    <flatrates>
                        <table>table2</table>
                    </flatrates>
                </entities>
            </module_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Namespace_Module</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </module_setup>
            <module_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </module_write>
            <module_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </module_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Block</class>
            </module>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
            </module>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

But nothing use still i have same problem

Anything wrong i did here

Any ideas ?

Comment: No not like that i can get multiple records for where c_id = 64; but now its working perfectly when i have only one record for where c_id = 64;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking whether the records on your table have the same id?
I have tried looking on that particular code on the core library and found out items on a collection must have unique ids or else it throws an exception.

```
<?php
public function addItem(Varien_Object $item)
{
    $itemId = $this->_getItemId($item);

    if (!is_null($itemId)) {
        if (isset($this->_items[$itemId])) {
            throw new Exception('Item ('.get_class($item).') with the same id "'.$item->getId().'" already exist');
        }
        $this->_items[$itemId] = $item;
    } else {
        $this->_addItem($item);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: So is c_id the primary key of your model?

Comment: yes but actually c_id & other details are in different table here(in this table) i'm storing c-id as foreign key

Comment: You should have mentioned it before. I assume you are getting the collections using join and the records are returning duplicate items. What you can do is to set a new primary key for that table, you can still use c_id as foreign key.

Comment: please take a look at my question i updated my tables structures also

Comment: Can you also show us the config file of your module, I need to see how your resource models set.

Comment: I hope everything is fine or else for single record it won't be work

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy i can't do like that because i need all records from the table

Comment: I think you are getting collection from let's say the main model, which is your table 1. But what you really want are models on table 2. If you do not have models setup for table2, you should create it as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54777/discussion-between-noia-0328-and-naresh).

Answer (score 0):

Its seem to have something to do with your primary keys, double check the `_init()` setting in your model since it using the wrong column for your primary key.

```
class MagePal_Module_Model_Mysql4_Xyx extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {   
        $this->_init('module/xyz', 'autoc_id');
```

Comment: already i tried this one also still i have same error & here i'm not giving autoc_id i'm getting c_id value from URL. if the value is autoc_id means it'll work perfectly But here is different.

Comment: c_id value i'm getting from URL i have to use the query like " Select * from table2 where c-id=64 " how can i do this & the actual problem is for this query i'm getting multiple records that means 4 records because of that its giving error like the " same id "64" already exist "

Comment: Did you clear you cache? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751694/magento-custom-model-wont-allow-db-table-changes